# How to check logstash agent is up and healthy?

Tags: logstash

I wrote a script to unzip and start logstash as service. How do I check it is actually up and healthy? Is there a status port? I'm using version 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no information available from logstash, something they're promising to fix for version 2.0.

Depending on what you're using it for, "healthy" can mean different things.

If you're using it as a shipper, you can check the sincedb file against the actual files themselves to see if it's up to date.

Comment: By healthy I mean: configuration is OK and process is running. IOW, do I need to reinstall (due to corrupted file system) or restart service  (because someone stopped it)?

Comment: Checking for a stopped process is best done with an external monitor.  Hopefully you have something like nagios or monit running to take care of that for you.